# How would you create this solution in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, build-process, build

I have project X, fully operational that compiles into `X.exe`
I have project Y, it has a reference to project X, and compiles to: `Y.exe; Y.dll`

I build project X's solution and the release folder has: `X.exe`
I build project Y's solution and the release folder has: `X.exe, Y.exe, Y.dll`

How do I remove the extra `X.exe` in project Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it's technically possible, it's not common practice to reference an exe... you usually reference a DLL
What I would do is extract the common parts into a class library project, and reference the resulting DLL in both executables

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but I was hoping for another easy way

Comment: currently doing that... next time I wont do this mistake again :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have the "extra" exe (I'm assuming you mean the compiled output of project X) in project Y's output directory because you have added a reference to it in the project. If you do not need a reference to it, remove the reference and it will not appear in the output directory. If you do need a reference to it, you will need the exe present otherwise your Y.exe will not run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the properties for the reference to the exe and set copy-local to false.

Comment: problem is I need the X.exe to run Y.exe

Comment: Then you've contradicted yourself. Either you need it or you don't. Perhaps you should be placing all your outputs into a single directory instead of multiple.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:** **you can't**, since you are using X.exe assembly in Y.

Using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) might help (to merge X.exe into Y.exe)

**Proper answer:** *you have to refactor* to split X functionality into a reusable class project and an executables that use it.

You can't. You are referencing